# Boost.Log: how to filter by current thread id

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, boost, filtering

I'm using Boost.Log, which is a part of Boost v1.54. I have a sink, which I want to only accept log messages from the current thread. How can I achieve that?

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(thread_id, "ThreadID", logging::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type)
std::stringstream stream;
logging::add_common_attributes();

boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(stream);
logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

boost::thread::id currentThreadId = boost::this_thread::get_id();

// At this line compiler complains about the '==' operator.
sink->set_filter(thread_id == currentThreadId);
```

Without the last line everything works fine, and when I configure sink formatter, it outputs the calling thread ID. What is the proper way to compare thread_id attribute with the currentThreadId?
I know I can use some custom attribute to tag messages with the current thread ID, and then filter them by that attribute, but what about the default boost's current_thread_id attribute? Is it usable for such a purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after spending half the night digging around I came across the (undocumented?) `boost::log::aux` namespace, where I found `boost::log::aux::this_thread::get_id()` function. It returns an object of the proper type which I am now able to compare with the `thread_id` keyword.
Now I wonder if the `boost::log::aux` namespace is meant for boost internal use only? Some time ago I used to utilize some internal features of boost mutexes/locks, and after the next library update they changed everything and I couldn't even compile my code against that new version of the library. So now I don't want to repeat my past mistakes :)

Comment: There is a `rec[process_id_attr].get().native_id()` function which returns a number. I found it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/boost-log/discussion/710021/thread/e90226f5/#9d5d